# Angular get error "$digest already in progress" when set the restrict attribut to 'E'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i  get error "$digest already in progress" when set the restrict attribut to 'E'.
here the directive code:

```
mainApp.directive('scoreDisplay',[
    function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                goal_1: 0,
                goal_2: 0,
                goal_3: 0,
                goal_4: 0,
                goal_5: 0,
                goal_6: 0,
                goal_7: 0
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl:'templates/directive-score-display-template.html',
            link: function(scope,element,attrs){}
        };
  }
```

]);

here the tag:

```
<score-display></score-display>
```

here the directive template:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td ng-model='goal_1'>1</td>
<td ng-model='goal_2'>2</td>
<td ng-model='goal_3'>3</td>
<td ng-model='goal_4'>4</td>
<td ng-model='goal_5'>5</td>
<td ng-model='goal_6'>6</td>
<td ng-model='goal_7'>7</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

This portion will throw an error:

```
        scope: {
            goal_1: 0,
            goal_2: 0,
            goal_3: 0,
            goal_4: 0,
            goal_5: 0,
            goal_6: 0,
            goal_7: 0
        },
```

The `scope` property of the directive is meant to declare how attributes on the element should bind to its scope. This should use `=`, `&`, or `@` depending on how/what you want to bind. It looks like you tried to bind in default values. This should be done in the `link` function instead, or just use `ng-init` in the template.

Next issue: Why use `ng-model` on `td`? That is meant for elements where you can enter or change data. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.

Just a note: I would use `ng-repeat` to make that template more DRY.

```
<td ng-repeat="item in '1234567'>{{$index+1}}</td>
<!-- or -->
<td ng-repeat="item in '1234567'>{{item}}</td>
```

[**Here's a working live demo**](http://jsbin.com/zuquqi/1/edit) that might be close to what you're trying to do.

```
<table>
  <tr ng-init="goals=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
    <td ng-repeat="item in goals track by $index">
      <p>{{goals[$index]}}</p>
      <input ng-model="goals[$index]">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you still have an issue after making these changes, then the problem exists elsewhere in your code.

Comment: sorry, there was a big mistake when i was copy/paste the code. the scope array was wrong there, it's placed in the controller.

Comment: when i call the template with the attribute templateUrl i'll get the error:$digest already in progress... when i change to the attribute template everything works fine, so want to find out whtas wrong.

Comment: @ChrobakStefan Either way, you can see that my code works. I pointed out everything that is wrong with the code you posted. I can't debug code that you're not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

The `scope` property of the directive can only accept `@`,`=`and `&` like @m59 said. You can't set the values there as the scope doesnt exist yet.

```
mainApp.directive('scoreDisplay', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'templates/directive-score-display-template.html',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
          scope.goal_1 = 0;
          scope.goal_2 = 0;
          scope.goal_3 = 0;
        }
    } })
```

You can only set scope variables/properties once a the directive has been picked up and `linked` to a function

Comment: sorry, there was a big mistake when i was copy/paste the code. the scope array was wrong there, it's placed in the controller.

Comment: What exactly is wrong. Edit your original post to describe your problem. Because I don't understand from your brief comment

Comment: mainApp.directive('scoreDisplay', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'templates/directive-score-display-template.html',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){}
    } })

this is my directive, when i do the template inside like:

return {
    template: "<div>....

everything is good, but when i use templateUrl i get the error and than the template is building after the error.